# Generic way of getting array up to last index: Include all indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have an index `i` running that indicates how to slice a particular array `a`. For example,

```
a = np.arange(10)
for i in np.arange(1, 5):
    print(a[i:], a[:-i])
```

Output

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
[2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[3 4 5 6 7 8 9] [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
[4 5 6 7 8 9] [0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

However, this will not work for `i=0`:

```
a[0:]
Out[67]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
a[:-0]
Out[68]: array([], dtype=int64)
```

Where my expected / required output would have been

```
a[0:]
Out[67]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
a[:-0]
Out[67]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

What is the reason for this asymmetry? Ultimately, I need to

- select less and less from either end
- Corner case: Select only one from each end (which I can do generically via `a[i:]` and `a[:-i]`, when `i==9`
- Corner case: Select all from both ends (which will not work, given that `a[:-0]` returns not the expected result.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Because `-0` is `0`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Generally that is not true. See for example the current standard for floating point arithmetics, which requires a sign even for zero. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 - in which case *numpy can treat them as the same*, but *they are not the same*

Comment: although IEEE-754 uses a signed magnitude representation. Even then `-0` is considered to be the *same* as `0`. Usually integers use however a 2-complement representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `-0` is `0` (at least in the integer domain where the most popular representation is 2-complement) and the unary minus is evaluated first. For floating points there are two *representations* for `-0` and `0`, but usually a programming language makes abstraction o that.

You can however use `None` in that case, so you can write it as:

```
a = np.arange(10)
for i in np.arange(0,10):
    print(a[i:], a[:-i or None])
```

For `i=0`, this returns:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```